# Not getting model class arrays value in swift 4 using swiftyjson and alamofire

Tags: json, swift, model-view-controller, alamofire, swifty-json

In View controller before appending data I get messegearray with proper data

But when I appending message array data into events not get going array data

simple event name , event id i got but maping with going array create issue

I think I doing some mistake when I intializing going array inside model class

Please let me know where I did mistake.I am first time tring to use MVC and swiftyjson

Here is summery of Model class

```
import Foundation
import  SwiftyJSON

class eventModel{

var eventId = String()
var eventName = String()
var eventUserGoing = [userGoingArray]()

init()
{}

init(json:JSON) {

    self.eventId = json["event_id"].stringValue
    self.eventName = json["event_name"].stringValue
    self.eventUserGoing = [userGoingArray(goingArrayJson:json["going_arr"])]

    print("event going model array \(self.eventUserGoing[0])")


    for i in 0..<eventUserGoing.count{

        print("user going array \(i) th data \(eventUserGoing[i])")
    }
}


}

class userGoingArray{

//var goingArray = [JSON]()
var userName = String()
var userGender = String()

init()
{}

init(goingArrayJson:JSON) {


    self.userName = goingArrayJson["name"].stringValue

    self.userGender = goingArrayJson["gender"].stringValue

}



}
```

Here is summery of controller class

1.Global event variable wit eventModel type

```
var events = [eventModel]()



override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()


fetchSwiftData()

}
```

2.Here is code of fetching json data using swiftyjson pods with alamofire

```
func fetchSwiftData(){

    let urlString = "http://rednwhite.co.in/webservices/event_details.php?user_id=22&club_id=1&selected_id=20"
    Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .get).validate().responseJSON { (response) -> Void in

        if let value = response.result.value{

            let json = JSON(value)


          } 

            let messageArray = json["message"].array


            for arr in messageArray!{

                    self.events.append(eventModel(json:arr ))
            }

            print("Message Array O th index data event name \(messageArray![0]["event_name"].stringValue)")

            Result:Message Array O th index data event name greeshma night

            print("user going 0th index data object \(messageArray![0]["going_arr"].arrayValue)")
```

Output of above line
[image]

```
var  goingArray = [JSON]()

goingArray = messageArray![0]["going_arr"].arrayValue
print("going array 0th index all data : \(goingArray)")
```

Output of above line

[image]

```
 print("going array 0th index data :\(goingArray[0])")
```

Output of above line
[image]

```
 print("going array 0th index user name data :\(goingArray[0]["name"])")
```

[image]

```
print("going array all user name :\(goingArray.map({$0["name"].stringValue}))")
```

Output of above line[image]

```
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, your problem is that you don't successfully parse the Json. 
You must implement your model as a struct like this :

```
struct eventModel {
    var eventId = String?
    var eventName = String?
    var eventUserGoing = [userGoingModel]?

    init(){
        self.eventId = ""
        self.eventName = ""
        self.eventUserGoing = []
    }

    init(json: [String: Any]) {
        if let evId = json["event_id"] as? String {
            self.eventId = evId
        }
        if let evName = json["event_name"] as? String {
            self.eventName = evName
        }
        if let evUserGoing = json["going_arr"] as? [[String: Any]] {
            for evUser in evUserGoing {
                let userGoing = userGoingModel(json: evUser)
                self.eventUserGoing.append(userGoing)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct userGoingModel {
    var userName = String?
    var userGender = String?

    init() {
        self.userName = ""
        self.userGender = ""
    }

    init(json : [String: Any]) {
        if let uName = json["name"] as? String {
            self.userName = uName
        }
        if let uGender = json["gender"] as? String {
            self.userGender = uName
        }    
    }
 }
```

And your request :

```
Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .get).validate().responseJSON { (response) -> Void in
        if let value = response.data {
            do {
                let json = try JSON(data: data)
                if let dictionnary = json.dictionnaryObject {
                    if let messageArray = dictionnary["message"] as? [[String: Any]] {       
                    for arr in messageArray {
                        self.events.append(eventModel(json: arr))
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                print("cannot convert to Json")
            }
        }
 }
```

Hope it will help you find your mistake.

Comment: Great...Man!! It Works. Thank you so much for comment .Best Model class structure easy to understand and also implementation.I want to deep dive into json parsing please  give me some documentation for that because swiftyjson  doesn't provide any documentation for mvc in swift

Comment: Glade it works for you ;) if you are in swift 4, you can experiment the new approach to parse JSON with Codable, no more needs to use swiftyjson. have a look here https://benscheirman.com/2017/06/swift-json/

Comment: definitely..and Big thumbs up for you.

Comment: I  need your help.I  can't access model class object values outside the alamofire scope using above code.

Comment: I don't understand what you need?  where is declared your "self.events" ?